# Get the string from the DataFrame column an assign to the other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a input data frame with columns:

```
Template                 Template Name
This is String  
This is String line 
This is Int 
This is Int Name    
This is String Name 
String Name is none 
Int is empty
```

Expected Output Dataframe:

```
Template                  Template Name
This is String              String
This is String line         String
This is Int                 Int
This is Int Name            Int
This is String Name         String
String Name is none         String
Int is empty                Int
```

I have tried the below code

```
    all_data['Template Name'] = all_data['Template'].str.contains('String')
    if all_data['Template'].str.contains('String').any() == True:
                all_data['Template Name'] = 'String'
```

but it just prints 'String' in all the cells, Please help me.

Comment: this `all_data['Template'].str.contains('String').any()` is true if any row is true, this is why it sets all rows to `String` I don't see any code that sets `Int` also are your templates always containing String or Int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Template Name'] = df.Template.str.extract('(String|Int)', expand=False)
print (df)
              Template Template Name
0       This is String        String
1  This is String line        String
2          This is Int           Int
3     This is Int Name           Int
4  This is String Name        String
5  String Name is none        String
6         Int is empty           Int
```